# Custom Event Notifier for apache camel doesn't work for exchange events

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a spring-boot application that implements a camel routing service. I want to know if the consumers queues are alive or not (because those queues are not in my system). I implemented a Event Notifier to know if the exchange sent event it's triggered or not. But my custom implementation of the Event notifier is not working. I can see in the logs when camel context event is triggered but this is all. No other event is captured by the event notifier.
Thanks.

This is may event notifier class:

```
@Component
public class MyLoggingSentEventNotifer extends EventNotifierSupport {
private static final Logger logger =    LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLoggingSentEventNotifer.class);
@Override
public void notify(final EventObject event) throws Exception {
  if (event instanceof CamelContextStartedEvent) {
  }

  if (event instanceof ExchangeSentEvent) {
     final ExchangeSentEvent sent = (ExchangeSentEvent) event;
     log.info("Took {} millis to send to: {}", sent.getTimeTaken(), sent.getEndpoint());
  }

  if (event instanceof ExchangeCreatedEvent) {
     final ExchangeSendingEvent sending = (ExchangeSendingEvent) event;
     log.info("Sending to to: {}", sending.getEndpoint());
  }
}
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(final EventObject event) {
  if (event instanceof CamelContextStartedEvent) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `isEnabled` method where you should filter which events you want to accept. And in your code, you only accept the camel context started event, and therefore you only get that. Instead either just return `true` for all events, or filter the ones you only want.